# Variable is not defined, I dont know how to define it

Tags: jupyter

```
Vsub=V.subs(-(2 - x**4)**(3/2)/6,0)
print('The volume when x=0 is',Vsub)

Name error: name 'V' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you using `sympy`?  Give more context.

Comment: What are you trying do?  Your question is a bit clearer after I correct the formatting ('x**4**' changes to `x**4`.  Still, who or what is the `V` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

In an `isympy` session,

```
In [114]: V = sympify('-(2-x**4)**(3/2)')                                                            

In [115]: V                                                                                          
Out[115]: 
         3/2
 ⎛     4⎞   
-⎝2 - x ⎠   

In [116]: V.subs({x:0})                                                                              
Out[116]: -2⋅√2
```